# Is it possible to programmatically get the ending location while in navigation with Google Maps?

Tags: android, navigation, maps

I know you can get the current location and direction in an Android app, but is it possible to get the end location of a running navigation session?

For example, if someone is already using Google Maps to navigate to some point a, and they run another app, can that app somehow get point a?

Thanks!

Comment: Not unless your app is the one that opened navigation in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't hook into other apps like so but you can get the last known location, but you'll have to figure out when to get it yourself or by help from the user. This is how you get the last known locaction:

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
// Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```